# apt-get install kernel source error

Tags: apt

**apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)**

gives me the below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic'
NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-oneiric.git
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux_3.0.0-17.30.dsc'
Need to get 99.9 MB of source archives.
Err http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main linux 3.0.0-17.30 (tar)
  500  ( The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your ISA Server administrator.  )
Err http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main linux 3.0.0-17.30 (diff)
  500  ( The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your ISA Server administrator.  )
Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.0.0.orig.tar.gz  500  ( The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your ISA Server administratorThe request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your ISA Server administrator.  )
Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.0.0-17.30.diff.gz  500  ( The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your ISA Server administrator.  )
E: Failed to fetch some archives.
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: looks like a network problem to me

Comment: How can we verify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [Microsoft ISA server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront_Threat_Management_Gateway) is blocking access to the `.gz` packages.

> The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your ISA Server
>   administrator.

If you're not administering the network, you should bring this up at your administrator to make the server allow this traffic.

Comment: I also suspected this but admin is saying that they have done nothing...not blocking anything. Is there anyway to verify that problem is really with network means our ISA server is blocking the request?

Comment: Well, there should be logs in your ISA server that contain entries about the rejection. On the other hand `apt` does not really know about „ISA”, it is the server that is sending the message.

Comment: The only solution i see is to run the command on a "live ip" bypassing the local network server. After then picture will be more clear.

Comment: Verified. Just run the command on "live ip" and its working with no issues. Problem is definitely with local ISA Server.

Comment: You can prove to them that ISA server *is* blocking ports by showing them that output, it's the ISA server providing that message and it's clear as day that the server is the problem in this case. Perhaps it was an admin who has since left that configured that firewall rule, you never know.

Comment: I was wondering if it was ever possible to download a `.gz` file before, maybe the problem had never shown up. These files are not really frequent under MS-systems, therefore I don't think it was any admin's fault, just the way things are set up.

Comment: As per my discussion with admin, he said that HTTP request is blocked by ISA server due to some "default" settings, nothing was blocked intentionally. Anyway, they have changed the ISA server settings and now the command is working under local network.

Comment: @lgarzo: Just this particular command is not working. Everything else is working perfectly, i never had any issue with apt-get.